# 自分で make した ImageMagick が PNG を扱えません

Tags: linux, imagemagick

初めてAWSでEC2の設定をしています。
PHPとImageMagickをインストールしたのですが、PNGが変換できません。

PHPのログを見ると、

```
[0] => convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
```

と出ていましたので、色々調べて、「libpng 」をインストールしました。
しかし、何度やってもPNGが使えるようになりません。

ImageMagickのディレクトリで、`sudo ./configure` と打つと、

```
PNG               --with-png=yes              no
```

と出ています。

インストールしたものは以下となります。

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX src]$ ls
autoconf-latest         ImageMagick.tar.gz    m4-1.4.18.tar.gz
autoconf-latest.tar.gz  libpng-1.6.29         zlib-1.2.11
download                libpng-1.6.29.tar.gz  zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
ImageMagick-7.0.5-4     m4-1.4.18
```

ImageMagickのパスにlibpngが通っていない気がするのですが、
どこをどうチェックすればいいのかわかりません。

どなたか、どこをどうチェックすれば、何が足りないのかわかるようになるか、
教えていただけないでしょうか？

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

※追記です。
libpng のインストールの具体的な手順は以下です。

```
cd /usr/local/src/
sudo wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.29.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf libpng-1.6.29.tar.gz
cd libpng-1.6.29
sudo ./configure --enable--shared
sudo make
sudo make install
```

`./configure --enable--shared` のところは、よくわかっていません。
（編集者注: `--enable--shared` は必要ありません）
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/orz---orz/20070329　のサイトを参考にしました。

Comment: OSは、Amazon Linuxを使っています。yumでImageMagickをインストールするとバージョンが古いという情報がありましたので、ソースからインストールしています。バージョンの関係ということであれば、最終的には、パッケージを利用したいと思います。

Comment: pkg-config の問題かもしれませんので、libpng.so のインストール先ディレクトリを明示的に指定すると上手く行くかもしれません。`./configure LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib'`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。上記で試したところ、質問欄の追記２のようなエラーとなりました。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: すみません、libpng の configure ではなく、ImageMagick の configure でお試しください。

Comment: ImageMagick の configure で試しましたが、追記３のようにさきほどと同じようなエラーとなりました。

Comment: 度々ですみません、gcc では -R オプションが使えませんので、`./configure LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib' LIBS=-lpng` で試していただけますか。

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます。試したところ、コマンドは通ったのですが、やはりPNGが使えません。config.logをみると、「Package libpng was not found in the pkg-config search path.Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpng.pc'」となっていました。

Comment: 解決しました！libpngを yum install libpng-devel で入れ直したところ、pngも使えるようになりました。皆様、どうもありがうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんは、ディストリビューションのパッケージ管理ツールである `yum` で libpng をインストールし解決されています。
以下は雑多な参考情報です。

---

まずは、`config.log` を "png" などのキーワードで検索し、状況を調査するのがよいです。

#### ライブラリのチェック

例えば、libpng がインストール出来ているかのチェックには `pkg-config` コマンドが使えます。
以下は実際に、ImageMagick の configure が行なっている方法です。

```
# インストール出来ていれば何も出力されないはず
pkg-config --exists --print-errors "libpng >= 1.0.0"
```

---

`pkg-config` がライブラリの情報を探す場所(`search path`)は、やはり `pkg-config` コマンドで確認出来ます。

```
pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
# 私の環境では以下が出力されます
# /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

野良ビルドしたライブラリは大抵 `/usr/local/` 以下にインストールしますから、上記のパスに `/usr/local/` 以下が含まれている必要があります。
もし含まれていなければ、

```
# 例: 常に必要ならば ~/.profile などに記入
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

のように、追加する事になります。

#### コンパイルのやり直し

コンパイルを `./configure` からやり直す場合には、`make clean` も行なった方がよいです。
（これが必要なのに忘れた場合、make が「やる事がない」と言ってくるので気付くとは思いますが）

```
# 例えば ImageMagick のコンパイル・インストールをやり直すなら、たぶんこんな感じ
./configure
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

#### sudo を使う箇所

全てのコマンドに `sudo` をつけるのは危険です。
これだと `root` で作業するのと変わりません。
ファイルの所有者を気にされているようですが、コンパイルは一般ユーザで進めて大丈夫です。
コンパイルなどは一般ユーザの権限で、**一般ユーザが書き込めるディレクトリで**行ない、インストール（`make install`）にだけ `sudo` を用いるのが定石です。

#### パッケージシステムの利用

必要な物を全てパッケージシステム外でコンパイルしてインストールなさっているようですが、これをやるならば、結構な作業量を覚悟する必要があります。
学習目的でないならば、こういった野良ビルドは最小限にした方がよいです。

例えば、ディストリビューションが提供する ImageMagick のパッケージが古すぎるとしても、他のパッケージ（autoconf、libpng など）は大丈夫かも知れません。
また、ImagiMagick 公式の RPM パッケージもありますね。
楽はしておいた方がよいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。また詳しく教えていただき、大変勉強になります。sudoをつける場所なのですが、./configure とかにもつけないと、permission denied のエラーになってしまいます。何か、根本的なところでミスっているのかもしれません。

Comment: pkg-config --exists --print-errors "libpng >= 1.0.0"　と打ったところ、追記４のような表示が出ました。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり、libpngをyumでインストールし直したところ、pngも使えるようになりました。初めてサーバーの設定をしていますので、わからないことだらけです。これから勉強させていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「./conf‌​igure とかにもつけないと、permission denied のエラー」はソースコードの展開をsudo付きでやってしまったせいで作業ディレクトリ自体がrootでしか書けなくなっているからだと思いますよ。

Comment: なるほど、そういうことですか。皆さまに色々ご教授いただき、感謝致します！